# Model class for JSON and same class for core data in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, class, core-data

I have class with parameters, example `Car`(subclass of NSObject), which I use like simple model:

```
class Car {
    var model: String!

    init(json: JSON) {    

        // ... parse JSON ...
    }
}
```

I can:

- Initialise with init's;
- Parse JSON data to this model;

Then use this class in my VC: add data, remove data, etc. Any what I need.

Also I want save this model to core data, but for this purposes I need other model:

```
class Car: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var model: String!
}
```

This class I can't use with parsing and simple initialisation.

But, I can create follow initialiser:

```
class Car: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var model: String!

    init() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext    
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Car", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        super.init(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: nil)
    }

    convenience init(json: JSON) {
        self.init()

        // ... parse JSON ...
    }
 }
```

Then I will use this class like:

```
var car = Car()
car.model  = "Toyota"
```

This is correct solution?
How I can use one model for all needs?

Comment: It's a solution, you haven't actually explained a problem / un-met need...

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `NSManagedObject` to represent Car.  In that `NSManagedObject` subclass create a method called `populateFromJSON(json:[String:Object])` then your creation is only slightly more complicated:

```
let aCar = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Car", intoManagedObjectContext:context)
aCar.populateFromJSON(myIncomingJSON)
```

And done.

btw, calling `super.init(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: nil)` is bad and will not yield the results you are looking for.

You really do not want to be overriding `init` methods on `NSManagedObject` subclasses.  Better to create a `populate` method and use the designated initialization options.